# adding, deleting, sorting, searching, and counting inside a listbox

Tags: c#, sorting, search, listbox, addition

So in this listbox I have the names in this order

> Abigal
>   Hannah
>   Tyler
>   Bill
>   Sasquach

The name of the listbox is called `namesListBox`.

Using TextBoxes and a different button for each input the user needs to input to:

- add a name
- delete a name
- and then search a name to where only that name shows up in the list box at that time.

Once that is complete use a button to count how many items are in the list. Use a different Button to Sort.

This is c#. I can't seem to get nameslistbox.sort or .count to work so any help with that would be great and I have no idea how to do the add, delete, and search.

```
private void showListButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    nameListBox.Visible = true;
}

private void countListButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> nameListBox = new List<string>();
    nameListBox.Add(addTextBox.Text);
}

private void sortListButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Well, this is mostly the Click event of the button. What we need is a code which you tried to solve your problem. Please note that SO users won't write the code for you, we're here to help solving problems with an existing code which causes errors or problems or does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the List instance in the click event method. This means, that you are creating a new List every time, when you click on the add button and the List is just inside your click method. You should make the List global:

```
private List<string> namesListBox; // this should be outside of the method
```

and initialize it in the constructor:

```
namesListBox = new List<string>();
```

now you can add elements like this:

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    nameListBox.Add(addTextBox.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As what icedragon stated in his comment, you are creating a new list every time you click the add button so you need to make it a global variable.

You might want to read more about `Linq` to handle your collection. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19154/Understanding-LINQ-C

```
private List<string> namesList;

public class YourClass()
{
    namesList = new List<string>();
}

private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     nameListBox.Add(addTextBox.Text);
}

private void sortListButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     nameListBox.Sort();
}

private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchedString = nameListBox.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(searchTextbox.Text);
}

private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     nameListBox.Remove(removeTextbox.Text);
}
```